# insert unbounded XML element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I did post many questions regarding inserting XML elements using XSLT, I am new to XSLT and I am learning while working on it. So thanks to everyone that helped me through.

Now, I came up with another question: so I am inserting a repeatable (unbounded) XML element so it will have the same xpath but different values for the element, when I put the xpath to match the template pattern it overrides the earlier elements that have been inserted. So is there a way to insert multiple elements into an exisiting XML using the same xpath? my input is the xpath where those elements should be inserted and the elements values. For example my input is:

```
xpath: /root/child
element to insert: new_element
with the values: new1, new2 new3
```

so the output should look like:

```
<root>
 <child> 
   <new_element>new1</new_element>
   <new_element>new2</new_element>
   <new_element>new3</new_element>
  </child>
</root>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: So you are trying to build/update an xml file with the requirements specified in a plain text file. Right?

Comment: Yes, but an xml file.. so I wrote a program to parse the input and extract the xpaths the elements to be written and their values.. now, the same code generates the xslt script, but what I am stuck on is how to add the multiple occurrences for one element under the same node. because all occurrences will share the xpath but have different values.

Comment: It would be useful for clear understanding if you post a real sample of the input file (the one containing the specs) and the xslt templates where you are stuck, if possible.

Comment: Yes empo, I will, just need some time to pull everything up. But the logic is the same as I have above.. I am not really stuck with a statement or something, I want to know if it's possible to do that with XSLT because I couldn't find any examples for inserting multiple values for an element.. also if it's possible then how. So I just put the root element as an example of input and output and how I can produce the output.. Thank you very much empo I do appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going probably to misunderstand your question, but it's hard to achieve your intents given the details in your post. I shouldn't guess here I know...anyway, are you interested in something like this...?

Example transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="newdata">
   <new_element>new1</new_element>
   <new_element>new2</new_element>
   <new_element>new3</new_element>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/child">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$newdata"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given this input

```
<root>
 <child/> 
</root>
```

Returns:

```
<root>
   <child>
      <new_element>new1</new_element>
      <new_element>new2</new_element>
      <new_element>new3</new_element>
   </child>
</root>
```

Comment: YES Sir.. Great guess :) this is what I exactly I was looking for.. Thank you very much empo.. saved the day!

Comment: The "program" you are working on is probably more complex than such a simple xslt code. That's why you should better invest some time in learning a bit of XSLT, you will save much more time and days probably ;-). However, you are welcome!

Comment: True, I will spend the weekend to learn XSLT.. and I am getting really interested in it now! Thanks again